Linux lock user after failed login attempts
Unable to get RH9 to lock out user for period of time after 3 failed SSH login attempts. I've modified /etc/ssh/ssh_config by enabling UsePAM yes and adding the following content to the following files. I've changed the order around w no luck. Any suggestions?
/etc/pam.d/system-auth /etc/pam.d/password-auth
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 unlock_time=1200 auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so
account required pam_faillock.so
